# How to extract multiple strings from html code using PowerShell script

Tags: string, powershell, extract

I have started my journey with PowerShell recently and I have already got stuck on this issue for a few days.
Basically I have a script that one of the variables contains a html block with random text and from that text I need extract certain strings and put into another variables.

Here is the example:

```
$text = "<div>\n Field1: Field1Value1\n </div> \n <div>\n <div>\n <div>\n Field2: Field2Value1\n </div> \n Field1: Field1Value2\n </div> \n <div>\n  Field1: Field1Value3\n</div>\n"
```

And this is what I need to pass further

```
$Field1 = "Field1Value1, Field1Value2, Field1Value3" //or in a list if possible
$Field2 = "Field2Value1"
```

There are more fields to extract but the idea is the same. I was able to get this working using the below function, but that only work for unique values.

```
function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $Text){

    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

    #Perform the opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($Text,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

    #Return result
    return $result

}
```

EDIT:
Here is my latest try. For some reason the `\n` was not working in some cases so I am now replacing everying as  `@@@`. Still only first value of each field is printed using the below code.

```
$originalString = "<div>Field1: Field1Value1\n</div><div>Field2: Field2Value1</div>\n<div>Field1: Field1Value2\n Field3: Field3Value1<br /></div>"
$formattedString = $originalString
$hash = @{}
$hash.'\n' = ' @@@'
$hash.'\t' = ' @@@'
$hash.'<br />' = ' @@@'
$hash.'</div>' = ' @@@'
foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
   $formattedString = $formattedString.Replace($key, $hash.$key)
   }

function GetStringBetweenTwoStrings($firstString, $secondString, $string){

    #Regex pattern to compare two strings
    $pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

    #Perform the opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($string,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

    #Return result
    return $result

}
$field1 = GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "Field1: " -secondString " @@@" $formattedString
$field2 = GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "Field2: " -secondString " @@@" $formattedString
$field3 = GetStringBetweenTwoStrings -firstString "Field3: " -secondString " @@@" $formattedString
```

Comment: Is that the literal text in the variable or did you add the `\n` in there while posting? Please show us your script so we can see how you obtain the variable.

Comment: Yes, `\n` is the last string, sometimes I saw `<br /> `or `\t` but I am unifying this with this  `$tempText = $text
$hash = @{}
$hash.'\t' = '\n'
$hash.'<br />' = '\n'
foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
   $tempText = $text.Replace($key, $hash.$key)
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390419/paolo) that you should normally use a HTML parser for this, but since it is unclear how you got the html in variable $text, I would suggest you try

```
$text = "<div>\n Field1: Field1Value1\n </div> \n <div>\n <div>\n <div>\n Field2: Field2Value1\n </div> \n Field1: Field1Value2\n </div> \n <div>\n  Field1: Field1Value3\n</div>\n"

[regex]::Matches($text,"Field\d+:\s[^\\<]+").Value | Group-Object {($_ -split ':')[0].Trim()} | ForEach-Object {
    $value = foreach ($val in $_.Group) { ($val -split ':', 2)[-1].Trim() }
    Remove-Variable $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $value
}
```

$Field1 now holds an array with values

```
Field1Value1
Field1Value2
Field1Value3
```

$Field2 contains a single string with value

```
Field2Value1
```

---

**Edit**

Looking at your last comment, where you say `Field1` is actually something like `First Name`, the code should be quite different..
(Why didn't you show us that in the first place??)

```
$text = "<div>\n First Name: Field1Value1\n </div> \n <div>\n <div>\n <div>\n Last Name: Field2Value1\n </div> \n First Name: Field1Value2\n </div> \n <div>\n  First Name: Field1Value3\n</div>\n"

$hash = @{}
# replace all tags and \n, \t, \f, \v in the string with two (or more) spaces, then split on those
($text -replace '</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|\\[nrtfv]', '  ').Trim() -split '\s{2,}' | ForEach-Object {
    # split the name and the value 
    $name, $value = ($_ -split ':', 2).Trim()
    $name = $name -replace '\s'  # take out spaces because they do not belong in a variable name
    # if the hash already has an element with this name, combine the value as array
    if ($hash.ContainsKey($name)) { $hash[$name] = @($hash[$name]) + $value }
    else { $hash[$name] = $value }
}
```

You can leave the values in the hash if I were you and use them as `$hash.FirstName` etc.

```
# show what is inside the hash:
$hash
```

> ```
> Name                           Value                                                                                                                  
> ----                           -----                                                                                                                  
> FirstName                      {Field1Value1, Field1Value2, Field1Value3}
> LastName                       Field2Value1
> ```

But if you must create separate variables of it, you can do

```
$hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Variable $_.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value        
}
```

$FirstName now holds an array with values

```
Field1Value1
Field1Value2
Field1Value3
```

$LastName holds a single string with value

```
Field2Value1
```

Comment: Nice, this does the same as my code but in more succinct and elegant way

Comment: Apologies for confusing you guys, I would never thought people would receive the example in a wrong way. Anyway thank you both for sharing your help and @Theo - your code works great in my case!